# Plot a bar plot on R, grouped in 2s

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Looking to plot grouped bar plots

data:

```
structure(list(Main = c(0.468893939007605, 0.0629924918425918, 
0.561410474480681), Total = c(0.388090040532888, -0.0706047151157143, 
0.483298239353565)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

intended output should look like this:

[image]

My current plot code which does not make sense to me:

```
barplot(main_total$Main, main_total$Total)
```

[image]

ggplot would be preferred but i have trouble coding it.any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your example code doesn't have 'H', 'M', or 'S' in it. Could you re-upload with complete data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `barplot` prefers transposed matrices.

```
m <- as.matrix(main_total)
```

Use `t` to transpose the matrix.

```
b <- barplot(t(m), beside=TRUE, ylab="Value",
             ylim=c(round(min(m), 1), round(max(m), 1)), col=3:4)
axis(1, colMeans(b), c("H", "M", "S"))
legend("topleft", legend=c("Main", "Total"), fill=3:4)
box()
```

***Gives***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the idea here since you didn't include the grouping variables in your example code.

```
df <- structure(list(Main = c(0.468893939007605, 0.0629924918425918, 
                    0.561410474480681), Total = c(0.388090040532888, -0.0706047151157143, 
                                                  0.483298239353565)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           -3L))
df$Group <- c('H','M','S') # Assign group variables
library(reshape2) # Data frame needs to be in long format
df.m <- melt(df,id.vars = "Group")
df.m

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.m, aes(x=Group,y=value)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge')
```

[image]